# How to solve the following errors in notag equation with the "amsmath" used?

Tags: amsmath, ctex

Coding:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctex}      % used for Chinese
\usepackage{amsmath}   % equation*

\begin{document}
    直角三角形有如下性质：
    \begin{equation*}  % for notag equation
        a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Errors and warnings:

```
Command `\acute' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\grave' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\ddot' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\tilde' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\bar' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\breve' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\check' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\hat' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\dot' already defined. \begin{document}
Command `\mathring' already defined. \begin{document}
Font shape `OMX/cmex/m/n' in size <10.53937> not available(Font) size <10.95> substituted
Size substitutions with differences(Font) up to 0.41063pt have occurred.
```

Screenshot:

With no `amsmath`, `equation*` can't be used:
[image: no <code>amsmath</code>]

With `amsmath`, errors still occured:
[image: with <code>amsmath</code>]

Platform:

```
TexLive2019, Windows10 64bit, TeXstudio2.12.18
```

Compiling messages:

```
xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "test".tex
```

After adding `\listfiles`, logs are:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    ctex.sty    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Chinese adapter in LaTeX (CTEX)
   expl3.sty    2019-11-07 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-11-07 L3 programming layer 
l3deprecation.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def    2019-04-06 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
  xparse.sty    2019-10-11 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2019-10-11 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
ctexhook.sty    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Document and package hooks (CTEX)
ctexpatch.sty    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Patching commands (CTEX)
  fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
ctexopts.cfg    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Option configuration file (CTEX)
ctex-engine-xetex.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 XeLaTeX adapter (CTEX)
   xeCJK.sty    2019/06/02 v3.7.4 Typesetting CJK scripts with XeLaTeX
xtemplate.sty    2019-10-11 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
fontspec.sty    2019/10/19 v2.7d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2019/10/19 v2.7d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
   xeCJK.cfg    2019/06/02 v3.7.4 Configuration file for xeCJK package
xeCJKfntef.sty    2019/06/02 v3.7.4 xeCJK font effect
    ulem.sty    2012/05/18
CJKfntef.sty    2015/04/18 4.8.4
zhnumber.sty    2019/04/07 v2.7 Typesetting numbers with Chinese glyphs
zhnumber-utf8.cfg    2019/04/07 v2.7 Chinese numerals with UTF8 encoding
ctex-scheme-chinese.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Chinese scheme for generic (CTEX)

ctex-name-utf8.cfg    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Caption with encoding UTF8 (CTEX)
indentfirst.sty    1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
ctex-c5size.clo    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 c5size option (CTEX)
ctex-fontset-windows.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Windows fonts definition (CTEX)
ctex-fontset-windowsnew.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Windows fonts definition for 
Vista or later version (CTEX)
    ctex.cfg    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Configuration file (CTEX)
 amsmath.sty    2019/11/16 v2.17d AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
 ***********
```

Comment: I find that "ctex" and "amsmath" are incompatible in TexLive2019. When I coding like this:
```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 Hello world!
\end{document}
```
I get the same errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It might be some encoding problem. Have you looked into the documentation of ``ctex`` on CTAN? I wanted to do that, but on CTAN the documentation is only available in Chinese, so unfortunately I couldn't understand.

Comment: I tried your example with lulatex and xelatex in an up to date texlive 2019 with no errors

Comment: Please provide more information.  Which operating system are you using and which tex engine (pdflatex, lualatex,....)?  Do you still get an error if you remove the `amsmath` package? On my system, just loading `ctex` gives complaints about unavailable fonts/fontsets - these complaints are to be found in the `.log` file, which is more detailed then the screenshot you provide.

Comment: without amsmath it is expected that `equation*` is not defined but you should not get the other errors.add `\listfiles` to your preamble then show (as text not a screenshot) the list of file versions from the end of the log

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is due to using a distribution that was not up-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(non-answer, but posting for file list)**

It works without error in an up to date texlive 2019 here. If you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and run with xelatex you should get a list something like this, but check the file versions:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    ctex.sty    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Chinese adapter in LaTeX (CTEX)
   expl3.sty    2019-11-07 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-11-07 L3 programming layer 
l3deprecation.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def    2019-04-06 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
  xparse.sty    2019-10-11 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2019-10-11 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
ctexhook.sty    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Document and package hooks (CTEX)
ctexpatch.sty    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Patching commands (CTEX)
  fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
ctexopts.cfg    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Option configuration file (CTEX)
ctex-engine-xetex.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 XeLaTeX adapter (CTEX)
   xeCJK.sty    2019/06/02 v3.7.4 Typesetting CJK scripts with XeLaTeX
xtemplate.sty    2019-10-11 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
fontspec.sty    2019/10/19 v2.7d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2019/10/19 v2.7d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
   xeCJK.cfg    2019/06/02 v3.7.4 Configuration file for xeCJK package
xeCJKfntef.sty    2019/06/02 v3.7.4 xeCJK font effect
    ulem.sty    2012/05/18
CJKfntef.sty    2015/04/18 4.8.4
zhnumber.sty    2019/04/07 v2.7 Typesetting numbers with Chinese glyphs
zhnumber-utf8.cfg    2019/04/07 v2.7 Chinese numerals with UTF8 encoding
ctex-scheme-chinese.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Chinese scheme for generic (CTEX)

ctex-name-utf8.cfg    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Caption with encoding UTF8 (CTEX)
indentfirst.sty    1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
ctex-c5size.clo    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 c5size option (CTEX)
ctex-fontset-fandol.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Fandol fonts definition (CTEX)
    ctex.cfg    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Configuration file (CTEX)
 amsmath.sty    2019/11/16 v2.17d AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
 ***********
```

Comment: I just added `\listfiles` and got the file list, but I couldn't understand the meaning of them. Could you help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: @VincentYin I thougfht you would have an old version of some package but the file versions are the same for all files except my  setup includes ctex-fontset-fandol.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Fandol fonts definition (CTEX) and yours ctex-fontset-windows.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Windows fonts definition (CTEX)
ctex-fontset-windowsnew.def    2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Windows fonts definition for 
 so I'm not sure, I'll have a look at that windows file.....

Comment: at the top of the log do you get `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3` ? @VincentYin

Comment: The top of the log is ```This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.1.1)  4 JAN 2020 08:34
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)```

Comment: @VincentYin something is very wrong with your installation, you have article.cls etc dated 2019/10/25   so you have the sources for the 2019 latex release but your format is from 2018 try `fmtutil-sys --all`  to see if it remakes the formats

Comment: What I installed is `texlive2019.iso 2019-04-10`. After installation, I updated by `tlmgr update --self` and `tlmgr update --all`. Dose it matter?

Comment: Fantastic! After `fmtutil-sys --all`, the top of the log is ```This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.1.4)  4 JAN 2020 08:53
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)```

Comment: @VincentYin that all sounds right but somehow you haven't got the updated format. what path do you get from `$ kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` I get 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: @VincentYin oh it updated! does your example work now?

Comment: Thanks so much. It is ok when compiling. And there are no errors now, only two warinings left. ```Font shape `OMX/cmex/m/n' in size <10.53937> not available(Font) size <10.95> substituted. Size substitutions with differences(Font) up to 0.41063pt have occurred.``` How to remove the annoy warnings?

Comment: they are OK, just ignore them

Comment: OK, thanks. This problem has annoyed me for several days. Finally solved.